# Objective-C ARC Strong and Weak references "object will be released after assignment" warning - but it doesn't get released

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-runtime

I'm doing this simple Objective-C exercise to understand ARC better, it's a program which should display R2D2 when the references are set to Strong, and fail when one is set to Weak. However, the code still compiles, even if there is a warning that says the object will be released.

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Robot.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        Robot *robot = [[Robot alloc]init];

        robot.firstString =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"R%d",2];
        robot.secondString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"D%d",2];

        NSLog(@"%@%@",robot.firstString,robot.secondString);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Robot.m

```
#import "Robot.h"

@implementation Robot

@end
```

Robot.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Robot : NSObject

@property (strong) NSString *firstString;
@property (weak) NSString *secondString;

@end
```

Thank you

Comment: What's your definition of "fail" here? Worse case you will see `(null)` instead of `D2`. The result may also be affected by optimization levels when compiling.

Comment: @rmaddy This is another case of using system classes to try and explore runtime behavior.  In this case, tripping over a tagged pointer. 

In general, when exploring the runtime, it is best to start with your own subclass of `NSObject` so you don't get surprised by the implementation details of the `NS*` classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, this is a fun one.  You're running into a tagged pointer.

```
@interface Robot : NSObject

@property (strong) NSString *firstString;
@property (weak) NSString *secondString;

@end

@implementation Robot
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        Robot *robot = [[Robot alloc]init];

        robot.firstString =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"R%d",2];
        robot.secondString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"D%d",2];

        NSLog(@"%@ %@",robot.firstString,robot.secondString);
        NSLog(@"%p %p",robot.firstString,robot.secondString);

        robot.secondString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"argy bargy foo foo %d",2];

        NSLog(@"%@ %@",robot.firstString,robot.secondString);
        NSLog(@"%p %p",robot.firstString,robot.secondString);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
 R2 D2
 0x325225 0x324425
 R2 (null)
 0x325225 0x0
```

Note that your weak string has an **odd address**.  But allocations cannot fall on odd addresses!  In fact, allocations on the heap are *generally* aligned by 16 bytes (though statically allocated special case strings may be even address only).

That odd address means there is a `1` in `bit 0`.  That indicates a *tagged pointer* is in use.  That is, the string is encoded in the address of the object and the runtime detects that the low order bit is set and, thus, special cases it to a tagged pointer.

In fact, if you look up `0x32` and `0x44` in an ASCII table, the former is the character `2` and the latter is the character `D`.   The `0x25` is the length of the string (2) and the class index (+ the low bit).

So, you never see the weak reference go to zero, *because there was no allocation involved*.   Without an allocation, there can never be a deallocation and, thus, the string reference can never be invalid.

The second string-- `@"argy bargy foo foo 2`-- doesn't fit in a tagged pointer and, thus, is a heap allocation.

Answer (score -3):

Compilers are clever. The compiler can replace

```
[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"D%d",2]
```

with

```
@"D2"
```

which is an NSString constant and will never get deallocated. Another possibility: An optimising compiler replaces

```
    Robot *robot = [[Robot alloc]init];

    robot.firstString =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"R%d",2];
    robot.secondString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"D%d",2];

    NSLog(@"%@%@",robot.firstString,robot.secondString);
```

with

```
    Robot *robot = [[Robot alloc]init];
    NSString* tmp1 =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"R%d",2];
    NSString* tmp2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"D%d",2];

    robot.firstString = tmp1;
    robot.secondString = tmp2;

    NSLog(@"%@%@",tmp1,tmp2);
```

and then with

```
    NSString* tmp1 =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"R%d",2];
    NSString* tmp2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"D%d",2];

    NSLog(@"%@%@",tmp1,tmp2);
```

and then with

```
    NSString* tmp1 =@"R2";
    NSString* tmp2 = @"D2";

    NSLog(@"%@%@",tmp1,tmp2);
```

and then with

```
    NSLog(@"R2D2");
```

Comment: In general, as I'm sure you know, a compiler can't inline or replace an ObjC method call. Are you sure that Clang actually has a special case like this for `initWithFormat:`? I'm even more skeptical about removing the allocation of `Robot`. You think that the compiler can know that those property accessors aren't overridden? It _certainly_ can't know that I didn't swizzle them out at runtime.

Comment: The compiler **can never optimize away a method call**.  Because every method call is dynamically dispatched, the result of calling said method **cannot** be determined until runtime.